# How to use JavaScript import/export without node.js?

Tags: javascript, html

The following code worked when run using Visual Studio Code live server. But threw an error when run as distinct file.
I tested it online on my web site and in place of  './course.js' and  './student.js' with the full URL path and the error returned were:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows readin the remote resource at .... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

and

```
Loading module from “...” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/octet-stream”)
```

In a different iteration in which I used che to set the request  header to allow CORS I was still unable to run the code properly as the browser returned  the following error:

```
  SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Please keep in mind that I am not using node.js, nor any form of server side rendering, but rather trying to import code without having to add  for each JS  file.

Example

File 1 (course.js)

```
export function Course() {
   this.name = '';
}
```

File 2 (student.js)

```
import { Course } from './course.js';

export function Student() {
   this.course = new Course();
}
```

File 3 (index.html)

```
<html ...
<body>
    <script type='module'>
        import { Student } from './student.js';

        var x = new Student();
        x.course.name = 'xxx';
        console.log(x.course.name)
   </script>
 ....
```

Answer (score -1):

https://gomakethings.com/an-intro-to-import-and-export-with-es-modules:

> ES modules also won’t run if you try to just open an HTML file in the
> browser using the `file://` origin. You need to run a local server for
> local development.

Bummer, right?